# Routing with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, hapi.js

I am trying to understand how to build a Node.js project.

I have followed a tutorial I found to make a chat app.

The routing between the server side and the client side is not working.
If you could explain to me why, or, maybe give me a good reference to understand how its all should work together ?

This is the server:

```
    var http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    var Router = require('router')

    var router = Router();
    router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
        res.end('Hello World!');
    })

    var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        fs.readFile("public/client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write(data);
            response.end();
        });
    }).listen(1337);


    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('message_to_server', function(data) {
            io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",{ message: data["message"] });
        });
    });
```

And this is the HTML with the client script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script> 
            var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");
            socketio.on("message_to_client", function(data) {
                document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML = (document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML + "<hr/>" + data['message']);
            });

            var request = $.ajax({
                           url: "/test",
                           type: "GET"  
                        });
            request.done(function(msg) {
                console.log(1111);
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });

            function sendMessage() {                
                var msg = document.getElementById("message_input").value;
                socketio.emit("message_to_server", { message : msg});
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wholeChat">                
            <div id="chatlog"></div>                
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="message_input"/>
                <button onclick="sendMessage()">send</button>
            </div>
        </div>        
   </body>
</html>
```

Maybe using express or hapi will make things more simple, but then I can't understand how do I load the view like I'm doing here with the `fs` module.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give some details on "not working"; did you get an error? Are things just not showing up without explicit errors?

Comment: Your router has no connection at all to your http server and thus isn't doing anything.  Not sure where you got that code from.  If you follow the example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/router you will see you are missing the part where your router gets connected to the http server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why are you trying send index.hmml like that, there is much easier way to do that, like ..

```
var connect = require("connect");
var serveStatic = require("serve-static");
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(2000,function(){
    console.log("Server running on 2000...");
});
```

And just type localhost:2000/yourIndexFile.html

Or you can use express (which is awesome module you should learn it)..

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = require("http").Server(app);

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});

app.use("/client",express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

serv.listen(2000);
```

And if you really really want to use 'fs' module try adding this to your code in response header.

```
onRequest = function(req,res){       
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(res);    
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(2000);
```

Comment: @bratibrat well ur route on serer is /test ..but you are calling /client/test check that